# scipy sparse matrix multiplication overflow

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I encountered the similar problem as in http://scipy-user.10969.n7.nabble.com/Help-Multiplying-two-sparse-matrices-td2472.html. So how can we use int64 to store the nonempty positions of sparse matrix to overcome this kind of overflow? PS, directly change the result matrix into dense one would not work because the dense version would still be too large to be load in memory.